# Access to ASP.NET error, help added upload field?

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, content-management-system

I am edited a clients website, this client's website was built years ago by a different developer. This developer added a forms module into the cms to make added forms simple. This little module works well however I am having problems with file uploading.

When creating the form there is the option to create a custom file upload field for the user to upload their own files and then the client would recieve it in an email. I am getting the following error when trying to send a test email though:

```
Exception Details: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '\\vnet-data-02.voloper.net\websites\client\files\dummy_girl.jpg' is denied.

ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6) that is used if the application is not impersonating. If the application is impersonating via <identity impersonate="true"/>, the identity will be the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated request user.

To grant ASP.NET access to a file, right-click the file in Explorer, choose "Properties" and select the Security tab. Click "Add" to add the appropriate user or group. Highlight the ASP.NET account, and check the boxes for the desired access.
```

ASP isn't my strong point so this doesn't make much sense to me.

Could anyone help me out please!

Comment: Did you try adding permissions as it suggests in the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Your site needs to be run using an authorized account.  One way is to implement [Impersonation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306158) with an account that has the needed access.

Comment: Hmm, the error only comes up when the USER submits a form using the upload function. I have all permissions to create the form/configure it and all of the other fields work ok, name, email, tel.no etc...

Comment: is '\\vnet-data-02.voloper.net\websites\client\files\dummy_girl.jpg' on the server where you are hosting the site?